# Pastie with API and language detection

Tags: api, syntax-highlighting, pastie

I'm trying to find a pastie like webservice that do perform *some kind of automatic* language detection (in term of programming language) and does the syntax coloring accordingly.

Most pastie websites do not have this feature I'd really love to have and use.

Thanks !

Comment: i couldn't find one such site in internet which would auto-detect the pasted script, normally i found is when a script is pasted and the language is set manually the syntax coloring is done accordingly otherwise they just treat them as text/plain only, can u name one site which does it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finished to develop my own tool to do that. It's called UU and performs automatic syntax recognition using `highlight.js`.

- http://uu.zoy.org is free and encode locally what you paste in your browser before sending it to the server.
- The API is WIP.

Answer (score 0):

Pygments has something close : http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/#lexer-and-formatter-lookup

```
>>> from pygments.lexers import guess_lexer, guess_lexer_for_filename

>>> guess_lexer('#!/usr/bin/python\nprint "Hello World!"')
<pygments.lexers.PythonLexer>
```

Not perfect but quite useful already.

But yeah I share your frustration with paste service, had the same. In my opinion actually the coloration should be done client side.

https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter
http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

are pretty nice in that regard.

Comment: Actually linguist has some of this feature too now: https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/master/lib/linguist